# custom database query using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have build a database and tables named `news` and `articles`.
I have inserted 1000 words of article on my table.

I'm able to query article from database but it shows full article on my browser and now I want to show articles with only 100 words then with a "read more" button.
When read more button will be clicked full article will be shown a another page.

Comment: Just a hint for future questions: You should try to include some code you have a problem with to make it easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select substring(detail, 1, 100) from articles
```

Assuming "detail" is a column in you table "articles"

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$word = strip_tags($word); // strip tags to avoid breaking any html

if (strlen($word) > 100) 
{    
    $wordCut = substr($word, 0, 100); // truncate string
    $word = substr($wordCut, 0, strrpos($wordCut, ' ')).'... <a href="/this/story">Read More</a>'; // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
}
echo $word;
```